# How to set the Image and the Text at the center of Button in android

Tags: java, android

I have created six buttons With an Image and Text...... I just want these image and text apears at the center of the button note that the text is just under the image and this... is my XML Code... if any one could solve this just write the XML Code downstairs, sorry for my bad English I hope this gonna be Understandable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/list"
                android:text="Order Station"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="2" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/power"
                android:background="#ff4545"
                android:text="Quick Order"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="4"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/coffeecup"
            android:text="Take Away"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: you want to crop the images to fit to the button size as a background and the text to still be centered ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either You have to use another layout (Linear or Relative) and place drawableTop on a TextView and use that LinearLayout as Button by giving an onClickListener.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"> //give onclick to this layout to act as a button
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/list"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Order Station"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="#ff4545"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/power"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Quick Order"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/coffeecup"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Take Away"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

or set height of button as wrap_content.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/list"
            android:text="Order Station"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks alot but It's realy helpful but I change this button to Relative layout as I can Put the Image and Text View as I need

Comment: yeah actually i mean to add another layout - linear or relative.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the images to crop and the text to stay centered you can just set the images to be the background of the button: `android:background="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE"`

Here's what it would look like as your xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Order Station"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/list" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Quick Order"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/power" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Take Away"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/coffeecup"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="4" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks alot but It's realy helpful but I change this button to Relative layout as I can Put the Image and Text View as I need – 7arooney